# Sql Server 2014 Stored Procedure blocked by Job

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, sql-server-job

I Have a Sql Server 2014 Stored Procedure (SearchArticleByNumber) that I'm using for searching data and which works fine until Job schedule starts which job executes additional (five) stored procedures which inserts, update or delete data from tables that I'm using for searching data with SearchArticleByNumber procedure...

I can see in Sql Server Activity Monitor that exec of SearchArticleByNumber is blocked by process which correspondent with execution of Sql Server - Job...

When Job finish or I manually kill the process then everything is normal again...

Can some one help me how to resolve this issue...

Thank You in advance...

Comment: You found what is the cause and you determined it is blocking..so you need to take next steps as well,try tuning those statements which are causing blocking ,by making them faster

Comment: Are the five procs using transactions?
Perhaps you need to look at transaction isolation level for SearchArticleByNumer.